# Not Able To Deploy Django App Because of This Error How To Fix It

Tags: python, django, mysql-cli

ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Answer (score 0):

Try google, "mysql build from wheel".

Find your operating system.
Download.
Try again.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings.py

Set DEBUG = 'None'

In case that does not work, refer to this tutorial - https://pythontuts.com/django/posts/301154532665841128/